# SQLiteException no such column while compiling

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite

```
exams = new Select().from(DataExam.class).groupBy("LessonName").where("Favourite = " + 1).execute();
```

I'm use this code to get data from sql db, but always i get this error

> SQLiteException: no such column: Favourite (code 1): , while
>   compiling: SELECT * FROM DataExam WHERE Favourite = 1 GROUP BY
>   LessonName

it's **DataExam.class**

```
@Table(name = "DataExam")
public class DataExam extends Model implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "Id")
String Id;

@Column(name = "ExamId")
String ExamId;

@Column(name = "CategorieName")
String CategorieName;

@Column(name = "CategorieText")
String CategorieText;

@Column(name = "CategoriePicture")
String CategoriePicture;

@Column(name = "CategoriePictureThumb")
String CategoriePictureThumb;

@Column(name = "CategorieSortOrder")
public String CategorieSortOrder;

@Column(name = "Favourite")
public Boolean Favourite;

@Column(name = "LessonName")
public String LessonName;
```

...more code

in what cases is such a mistake possible except for the columns not found

Comment: These kind of errors are sometimes cause by a space Try this and give your feedback ,Remove a space between `"Favourite = "` so it can be `"Favourite="`

Comment: @Xenolion Space isn't an issue in that case. It would be an issue in a column name.

Comment: @Dmitri Let's bet you added or renamed that column **after** a previous app execution?

Comment: Ooooh probably or he used a ready made database! and capitalize some letters!

Comment: @Xenolion Column names and table names (as well as function names and view names) are case insensitive, in SQL.

Comment: Ooooh my bad!!! I am java addict I cant believe I forgot that!! @BernoulliGate

Comment: @Xenolion No worries.

Answer (score 0):

This error mostly occurs if column name is mis-spelled or column is not being created. You can verify that either your columns are actually being created or not. Use this library to see if the columns are being created.
[Local Database Viewer Library](https://github.com/facebook/stetho) it is an amazing library.